# Django - Handle all exceptions with custom templates

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to throw exceptions with any status code. I have this template structure

```
templates
|---error
|   |----401.html
|   |----403.html
|   |----404.html
|   |----451.html
|   |----500.html
```

Is there any way to raise an exception something like this: `raise Error("Not available here!", status_code=451)` and this will automatically show the `templates/error/451.html` template? And when a server error occurs, `templates/error/500.html` should be rendered.

I tried using `handler401`, `handler500` and raising an custom exception but nothing works...

```
# exceptions.py
class HttpResponseNotAuthenticated(HttpResponse):
    status_code = 401


# views.py
def pseudo_view():
    return HttpResponseNotAuthenticated("Please login")
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Answer (score -1):

Errors are handled out of the box with Django which I am guessing that is what you are referring to when you say “nothing works”

You need to override this functionality like so:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Specify the handlers as seen in your URLconf (setting them anywhere else will have no effect).

Comment: That's exactly what I did and it still doesn't work. I have `DEBUG = False` and I checked everything but it just shows me a white page with the text.